# Why osgi config property removes '\' character

Tags: osgi, aem

I have to save some private key in sling:OsgiConfig xml and value looks as below :

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEv....++ene\nIGSZKe
QrbJSbWO0GiI=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

The problem is after the configuration is deployed then all '\n' character is replaced by 'n' and hence private key becomes invalid. Is there any way to tell OSGI container not to remove ‘\‘ ?

I am reading the config as

```
 PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get("private_key"),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution: If any one else facing this issue then you have to replace new line '\n' with `&#xa;` in your config xml file. AEM does not understand the '\n', so it has to be replaced with this `&#xa;`. I am not sure why is this done in this way.